# How to disable data type check while pushing data to Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I have two SQL serves one is SQL server 2005 and other SQL server 2008.I push data from SQL server 2005 to SQL server 2008 using Linked Server.I want to improve performance of data transfer. Few days back I cam across one article (I don't remember exact site name) which mentioned  while inserting data in remote server you can disable data type check which can improve performance.He had mentioned one Set Command. I don't remember that command .Guys can you please help me to find out this command.I check with MSDN site but no help.

Also if you have any other performance improvement tricks please let me know.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have asked the same question at: [Performance improvement in linked server-Disable data type check](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/84c55dee-e47b-486b-aa0f-43eb8a9c4bee/performance-improvement-in-linked-serverdisable-data-type-check?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

> I push data from SQL server 2005 to SQL server 2008 using Linked Server.I want to improve performance of data transfer.

**Highly recommend to use SSIS.** Linked servers are not meant to push data. Also, depending on the amount of data you are pushing or pulling (direction matters!!), the performance of linked server will always be slow + the n/w bandwidth plays an important role as well.

Refer to my answer for : [**Which one is more efficient: select from linked server or insert into linked server?**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46302/8783)

> Few days back I cam across one article (I don't remember exact site name) which mentioned while inserting data in remote server you can disable data type check which can improve performance.He had mentioned one Set Command.

AFAIK, there is no such command in SQL Server to disable data type check which improves performance !!