# Is it possible to JOIN to a Primary database from a Replication instance?

Tags: sql-server, replication, join

I have a database on a Replication server that doesn't exist on the Primary server.

There are stored procedures on the Replication server's DB that join to tables in other databases on the Replication server. These *should* be joining to tables on the Primary server.

Is this possible? If so, how?

This is an example of what it's currently doing:

```
UPDATE  c
SET     CRP_Id      = be.EventId
FROM    #TempEvent be
JOIN        CRP.dbo.Payments c -- *should* be joining to CRP on Primary, not Replication
    ON  c.CRP_TransactionId     = be.SourceTransactionId
WHERE   be.EventTypeId  in  (
                                @MyEventTypeId
                            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use linked server and use four part naming `linkedservername.dbname.schema.object`

Also refer [my answer on efficient way of pulling data when using linked server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46302/8783)