# Linked Server Performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, linked-server

I have three `MS SQL Servers`, 2016. 1 source and two destinations.

There is a linked server setup from each destination server to the source.

We execute a simple select query from each destination server to the source server using `OPENQUERY`.

The query from destination 1 returns in 1 minute while the query from destination 2 returns in 7 minutes.

All the servers are in different data centers and we have checked the network, and we have not found any issues. What else can we check?

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se. You could add the actual execution plan to [pastetheplan.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) That way we can have some more insight as to what you are dealing with.

Comment: My answer [Which one is more efficient: select from linked server or insert into linked server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46302/8783) will help you.

Comment: Hi, Are both destination server databases using the same database compatibility mode? IE 130 (SQL Server 2016). I have found great differences with certain queries between the 2, and if one is in SQL 2008, its using the older cardinality estimator, creating very different query plans which can result in very different query execution times.